# Вывод из из базы данных с конца

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь вывести из бд записи с последней до первой.

```
$list_wall = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM  `Users_List_Wall` WHERE `post_user`='".$_USER['id']."' DESC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($_WALL = mysql_fetch_assoc($list_wall))
{

}
```

Пишет ошибку

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC' at line 1
```

Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых

```
 DESC
```

Заменяем на

```
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Во вторых вам вернётся всего одна запись, так как Вы выборку делаете по id. А он уникальный. Значит скорее всего Вам это нужно убрать из запроса. Вы скорее всего хотите так

```
SELECT * FROM  `Users_List_Wall` ORDER BY id DESC
```